# Hotkey to button in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How do  i add a hotkey to this button?
The button right now, if you click on it with your mouse it will activate the microphone so you can talk and other people can hear you, if you click it a second time it will de-activate the microphone so nobody can hear you.

I need to make the "Ctrl" Key, activate it and deactivate it

```
    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.Control Then
        sooket.Client.SendCommand(New Command(CommandType.jampee, sooket.Client.IP, UserName & "|" & NameMic & "|" & Roomname.Trim & "|" & "plassmic" & "|" & "microphoneee.png" & "|" & "|" & "okmic" & "|" & "Timeok" & "|"))
        ' mic()
    Select ToolStripButton1.Text
            Case "Off"
            Case "On"
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: please explain this code :        Select ToolStripButton1.Text
                Case "Off"
                Case "On"
            End Select
        End If   Also only post in your question. You can always edit it, so delete that answer edit your question and be specific what doesn't work

Comment: I explained, Off = mic off, On = Mic on. toolstripbutton1.text is a button called "Mic" if they click the button it allows them to talk on the microphone and if they turn it off, it disables it, i need it so they can click the CTRL button on keyboard to activate microphone

Comment: The CTRL key isn't activating the microphone @Claudius

Comment: `toolstripbutton1.text is a button called "Mic` is not possible. It's either one or other

Comment: @Claudius the button on the form says "Off"

Comment: And you want it to say YES?

Comment: @Claudius when i click the button, it turns to "On" this enables the audio from their microphone and then disables it when they click it again, i need a CTRL key to do it instead of clicking

Comment: @Claudius no i need a hotkey to enable their microphone by clicking CTRL key on keyboard, and the same hotkey to disable it if pressed a second time ..

Comment: Thats a different question. Show me a working code for that and I will integrate it.

Comment: please see update for correct switch statement

Answer (score 1):

Truly you shouldn't use `Ctrl` for that. You can put `&` before letter that you would like to be shortcut in `ToolStripButton1.Name`. But if you must this should work:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.Control  Then
        'Your code here
    End If
End Sub
```

Correct format with switch statement:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.Control  Then
        Select Case ToolStripButton1.Text
            Case "Off"
              ToolStripButton1.Text = "On"
            Case "On"
              ToolStripButton1.Text = "Off"
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: shouldn't it be in previewKeyDown ? as the CTRL key doesn't raise the keydown event...

Comment: @Claudius the code isn't working. check my answer below

Comment: @Claudius where am i putting the switch code? i just get tons of errors, forgive me im quite new at vb.net

Comment: @Claudius CTRL key still isn't activating the microphone

Comment: Above code changes text of ToolStripButton1. For working with microphone ask another question.