# hotkey/CTRL key with activating and disabling microphone

Tags: vb.net

```
    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.Control  Then
        Select Case ToolStripButton1.Text
            Case "Off"
              ToolStripButton1.Text = "On"
            Case "On"
              ToolStripButton1.Text = "Off"
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

I am trying to make it so that when a user/person clicks their "CTRL" key on their keyboard, it will activate the microphone so they can talk to users in the chat room. When they press the button again it will de-activate it and drop their microphone so someone else can talk!

Please assist me, I am stuck! :)

I have been told to post a NEW question so some one else can help me with the UPDATED / FIXED code!

Comment: Why are you asking this question again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hotkey to button in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693498/hotkey-to-button-in-vb-net)

Comment: I was asked to re-post it with the fixed code as he could't help me.

Comment: This is a genuine question.

Comment: [GetAsyncKeyState()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) - [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getasynckeystate).